# Is it possible to view the history of label use in Gmail?

Tags: gmail, gmail-labels

Is there a way to view a revision history of labels in Gmail—for instance,  to find all messages that where Archived in a particular day?

Use case:  used Boomerang program to have 100+ messages return,  took messages out of inbox;  Boomerang failed,  and now I'd like to find those important messages that no longer have the Inbox label.

Comment: Can you find the boomerang label?

Answer (score 2):

Not possible.

You can't filter, search or lookup when a label was added or removed from an email.